# Lumia 925 doesn't charge

Tags: 8.1, battery, lumia-925

I bought my Lumia 925 in October 2013. It was running well and I used to love the battery life. However, after updating my phone to Windows Phone 8.1 I started having problems with battery life. Earlier I used to charge only once in 24 hours, but after upgrading I had to charge it at least twice every 24 hours for it to run smoothly. I also found a strange bug: even if I don't put it on charge, the battery sign shows that it's charging. I've never used a wireless charger.

In October 2014, all of a sudden I found it that it doesn't charge at all. I've had it repaired twice, and although the charging problem was temporarily fixed, battery life remained the same. Worse, a few days later it stopped charging again.

What should I do? Should I have the phone repaired again? If so, what should I tell them to change internally (maybe the battery)? Or should I simply throw it away?

Comment: You need to make you question more objective. Just say what is your problem and what you already tried to solve. Or I will need to close it.

Answer (score 1):

If the battery life was working great, then it suddenly changes; the most likely cause would be an app or apps that are running in the background and draining the battery.

Run the Battery Saver app.  It will show the apps in the order of their usage.  Which apps have the highest usage?  The Battery Saver app will show foreground and background usage.

Apps that use GPS will draw down the battery fairly quickly, keep an eye out for that.